# importing JSON file to MongoDB using command line (Robo 3T)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I want to import a JSON file to MongoDB collection so for that i google it and it show me the followed syntax:

```
mongoimport --db <Database Name> --collection <Collection Name> --file <File Path>
```

and [here](https://nisorness.com/data/2017/7/28/load-json-files-to-a-mongodb-database-using-mongoimport-in-linux-or-windows) is the link. I copied the same thing and typed on robo shell it through exception. can anybody let me know what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: `mongoimport` is run from Operating System command line.

Comment: `mongoimport.exe` is a stand-alone application, not a MongoDB command. You have to run it from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import data into MongoDB use windows command line (cmd) as `mongoimport` is not mongoDB command.

`NOTE: Make sure that mongoDB paths are added in environmental variables`

Check out the screenshot!
[image]